# What is the highest voted comment of all time?

Tags: support, comments, data-explorer

Is there a way to see the highest voted comment on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 12):

It's relatively easy to find with [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/945792/top-scoring-comment).

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result#comment8132455_6841333) on  [Why is subtracting these two times (in 1927) giving a strange result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333) by [Costi Ciudatu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/262683) has a score of 1310. By the time you read it, it might be higher already because of the Meta effect.

The SQL query is quite simple; if you're interested, please take the [SEDE tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) which teaches you some SQL basics *and* the Stack Overflow data model.

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 Score, PostId AS [Post Link], UserId AS [User Link], Text
  FROM Comments
  ORDER BY Score DESC
```

Comment: I don't find this question useful at all. Interesting, maybe. But useful? Is it useful to know which comment is the most voted?

Comment: As of today, it has a score of 1337. It is indeed elite.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to use SEDE.

Try with [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/945793) query.

```
SELECT TOP 10 
postID [Post Link], Score, Text

FROM 
    Comments
ORDER BY Score Desc
```

Comment: The results are disappointingly boring questions actually, with one exception: [automagically finding Waldo!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479058/how-do-i-find-waldo-with-mathematica).

Comment: @Gimby I found the gz/zip/zlib answer an interesting read. And I flagged the third one as no longer needed! (the comment's suggestion is already edited in the question)